# How to duplicate value of array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays of integers, e.g.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
b = [7, 8, 9]
```

I would like to repeatedly duplicate the value of `'b'` to  get a perfectly matching array lengths like this:

```
   a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]   
   b = [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7]
```

We can assume that `a.length > b.length`

Comment: Are you going to combine the arrays afterwards?

Comment: If length of `b` goes into length of `a`, `n` times you can write `b*n`.

Comment: yes im going to sum each value by index. think inject method would do just fine
and i set 'b' value for only 3 entries, anyway thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Is this for a cipher?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
b = [7, 8, 9]
```

then you can do:

```
b.cycle.take(a.length) #=> [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7]
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/JJ3x/2.js"></script>
```

See [`Array#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle) and [`Enumerable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) for more details.

Comment: Nice use of `take`.

Answer (score 2):

I would have used `Array#cycle` had it been available, but since it was taken I thought I'd suggest some alternatives (the first being my fav).

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
b = [7, 8, 9]

[*b*(a.size/b.size), *b[0, a.size % b.size]]
  #=> [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7]    

Array.new(a.size) { |i| b[i % b.size] }
  #=> [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7]

b.values_at(*(0..a.size-1).map { |i| i % b.size })
  #=> [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7]
```

Comment: inspired by your answer, another method `a.map.with_index { |_,i| b[i%b.size] }`